# How to determine bonded devices so a Bluetooth RFCOMM Server knows who to connect to

Tags: c++, linux, bluetooth

I have an RFCOMM client/server setup based on the example found at: http://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/x502.html  I am using the bluez stack on a Linux system and writing c/c++ code.

What I can't seem to figure out is how do I restrict connections to the server from only bonded/paired devices.  I've searched Google and have come up empty on some kind of example code that would accomplish my goal.

Basically I'm going to have 2 devices paired to each other and communications will start, but I only want the server to allow a connection from the device it is bonded to.   There will be many device pairs running so this check is necessary to know exactly which devices are communication to each other.  Any connection attempt found on the listen socket from a device it is not bonded to should result in a refused connection of some sort.

Currently it doesn't matter if the device connecting to the server is paired to the same server or not as the server accepts any connection that hits the listen socket.

I guess in essence I want to know how to determine what devices I am bonded to, if any, on the client and server.  I thought the Bluetooth protocol would handle this for me, but it seems as I am mistaken when running through some tests.

Thanks to anybody that can help!

Answer (score 0):

You could disable further pairing by configuring etc/bluetooth/hcid.conf (set pairing to none).  Devices that have already been paired would be able to communicate using the stored link keys under /var/lib/bluetooth//linkkeys

Comment: Well the issue with this is that unpairing and repairing between devices can occur.  So just disabling paring is not a good option.  Basically there is a UI and a device.  When a device is connected to USB all other paring is removed and a new one is made via an OOB mechanism.  When you have a UI and device paired and you pair the device with a new UI via OOB. The device is now paired to the new UI, but the original UI still thinks it's paired to the device.  The comm retry loop kicks in and it talks to the device again even though the device is not paired to it any more.  This is an issue.